# Most efficient way of MySQL rows?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, full-text-search, sql-like

I know very little of MySQL. Right now I've a table with close to 1,000,000 entries and I wish to search for a particular string in a particular column and return the columns.

I've seen `LIKE` but I've read it slow for such huge entries. I've heard Fulltext-Indexing it a better option for searching.

I use phpMyAdmin for viewing my MySQL database. I do not know what exact modifications I need to make to my table and the function that should be used thereafter?

**PS:** Also, is it possible to pattern match with `AGAINST` as in `LIKE`

Comment: *"I know very little of MySQL. Right now I've a table with close to 1,000,000 entries"* - So why take on something as big as a million rowed project? Kind of hard to jump in the deep end when you hardly know how to swim ;-)

Comment: and a million is big?

Comment: ok a million and one; now that's big-'er ;-)

Comment: Can you provide a bit of specifics and what you have so far, please?

Comment: I'm using the following query : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp @MatteoSp Okay, lets make it 10 M :)

Comment: Now, 10 M we like! Google "query a large database mysql" ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FULLTEXT index to speed up searching the table. It has, however, some limitations - it works only on MyISAM tables (unless you are using MySQL [5.6.4 or newer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-restrictions.html)), you need to specify it over all columns that you want to search at once and you can only search for words that are longer than a limit set globally to whole database server (default is 4 characters)

Either use PhpMyAdmin to create the index, or you can do it manually, the syntax is rather simple:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD FULLTEXT (column_you_want_to_search);
```

Or for more columns:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD FULLTEXT (column1, column2, column3);
```

Then you can ask the database, which rows contains some words:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE MATCH(column_you_want_to_search) AGAINST ('search query')
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE MATCH(column1, column2, column3) AGAINST ('another query')
```

There is also option to search in "boolean mode", where you can specify which words you want, don't want or use asterisks as wildcards. See [this MySQL reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) for more.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be what I was looking for. Any idea how long a list with 10 million entries will take to search with this?

Comment: Saying "it only works on MyISAM" is false as you point out. If people are running historical versions of MySQL, that's their problem. 5.6.4 came out in 2011, after all.

Comment: @tadman I agree, however I think it's still quite important fact to note. Sai (or some other reader who might google this answer) might be running older MySQL and he would be confused why it doesn't work.

Comment: Totally understand, especially with the extremely sad state of some hosting providers running versions of MySQL used by the ancient Egyptians to build the pyramids. In terms of phrasing, though, you might want to mention the MyISAM part as a caveat, rather than first thing. It's like saying PHP doesn't support objects...unless you're using PHP5.

Comment: @SaiKrishnaDeep The good thing about indexed search is that it's not affected by number of rows as much as standard condition in "where" clause. The DB server keeps track of all words in table together with a reference on which rows the word can be found, so that it doesn't need to scan each row by row every time - it just goes straight to the requested rows and fetches them. 10 millions should not be problem unless something is wrongly set.